# Understanding tensor fields

Tags: vector-analysis

This is just a simple question:
Is every vector field a first-order tensor field?

I understand the definition of vector field, but I have problems understanding first-order tensor fields.

Answer (score 1):

Before going to tensor **fields** start with tensors!  A "tensor field" is simply a function that assigns a tensor to every point.  You don't say what definition of tensor you use but there are some definitions that specifically *define* a vector to be a first order tensor.  More generally, a tensor is any function of the coordinates that transforms homogeneously as the coordinate system changes.  That is, if tensor A= 0 in one coordinate system then A= 0 in all coordinate systems.  Since that is true of a vector, yes, a vector is a tensor and so a vector field is a tensor field.

Comment: Is a tensor an element in a vector space (in the algebraic sense), then?